# How to move window to other workspace with right side dock

Tags: multiple-monitors, workspaces

I'm learning Ubuntu for the first time and I was looking into the workspace system. I've seen that you can move a window to other workspace by dragging a window in the Activities window to the workspace that is on the side (that peeks next to the active one).

My issue is that I use the dock placed on the right side of my screen and this seems to interfere with this dragging process (I've tried to change the dock to the bottom of the screen and my issue is gone, but I'd like to keep the dock on the right side).

Is there any way to achieve this while keeping my dock on the right side of the screen?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 22.04 the shortcut key combination to move a window to the right is <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Left Super</kbd><kbd>Page Down</kbd> and to move a window to the left workspace is <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Left Super</kbd><kbd>Page Up</kbd>

The <kbd>Super</kbd> key is normally set as the left <kbd>Windows</kbd> key by default.

Since that works both ways if the dock is positioned on the left, it follows that it will also work if the dock is positioned on the right.